# Issues displaying multiple data points on tabs in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, so looking for some guidance for a problem that I'm having; I have a JSON file store which I'm successfully reading data from, which is in the form:

```
{
"sites": [
    {
        "name": "S001",
        "description": "Joes's 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "S002",
        "description": "Fred"
    },
    {
        "name": "S003",
        "description": "John"
    },
... etc ...
    {
        "name": "S020",
        "description": "Mary"
    }
]
```

}

I'm trying to use the `md-tabs` directive to loop through this, displaying 10 items at a time within a single tab; I've got it working for *each* item using the code below (sorry for the messy workings):

```
    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex"  style="border: 1px solid red; background-color: white; color: black;">
      <md-tab ng-repeat="site in sites.sites" md-on-select="onTabSelected(tab)">
        <md-tab-label>
          Tab {{ site.name }}
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          {{ site.description }}
          <p>Length of Array: {{sites.sites.length}}</p>
          <p>Pages: {{ sites.sites.length / pageSize }} - ({{ currentPage }} of {{((4.9 + sites.sites.length) / pageSize | number:0)*1 }})</p>
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
```

But I'm struggling to find how to make the tabs read "Tab1", "Tab2" and display only 10 pieces of information per page - is this possible using tabs, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

With thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I went down a different route in the end; using the JSON list, I've calculated the highest page by using the length + 4.9 (too take it to the next integer) and going through the `number` filter to produce a range of 1 to n:

```
    <span style="width:120px; display: inline-block;">
        <md-select ng-model="pageStart">
          <md-option ng-repeat="n in range(1,((4.9 + sites.sites.length) / pageSize | number:0)*1)" ng-value="{{( n * pageSize ) - pageSize }}">Page {{n}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </span>
```

The `ng-value` then binds the page number to the selected drop down option, which is later used in an `ng-repeat` as the starting point for the main loop:

```
    <div class="table" ng-repeat="site in sites.sites | limitTo: pageSize : pageStart">
```

This then displays the correct number of items per page.

Hope that helps someone in the future needing to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

General rule is making your model in such way, co view is as simple as possible. So you want some tabs with sites, ok: `tabs: [{sites: [...]}, {sites: [...]}]`

fill it in controller:

```
vm.tabs = [];
let currentTab = null;
sites.forEach(site => {
  if (!currentTab || currentTab.sites.length > 9) {
    currentTab = {sites: []};
    vm.tabs.push(currentTab);
  }
  currentTab.sites.push(site);
})
```

And now your html:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
   <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" md-on-select="onTabSelected(tab)">
      <md-tab-body>
          <div ng-repeat="site in tab.sites">{{ site.description }}</div>
...
```